# Mail command executing commands inside of string passed in as message body

Tags: bash, unix, sh, sendmail

Ive got a script that checks if a process is running or not, using `ps -ef` and some `grep`.  If the process is running, it does nothing.  If the process isnt running, it restarts the process, and then sends an email to me stating that the process died.

This script currently runs ever 5 minutes from a admin account's crontab.

Peusdocode + problem code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# declare a ton of environment variables.
ATONOFVARS=/lots/of/qualified/paths

# declare relevant logging functions
loggingFunction()

# declare failure message to pass into mail  (real code)
PAGEMESSAGE="MyServer: process not found in ps -ef.  Attempting to Restart... Please check log file in /tmp"
PAGESUBJECT="ProcessHealthCheck.sh - MyServer: process not found in ps -ef"
EMAILLIST="my.email@mycorp.com"

# do the actual check (back to peusdo code)
if [ $(ps -ef | grep process | grep adminAccount | grep -v grep | wc -1) ]
    restartProcess()
    FAILURE=1
fi

# log the failure and send an email to me (real code)
if [ $FAILURE -eq 1 ]
    then
        logMsg ""
        logMsg "The process is not detected in ps -ef!"
        logMsg "Restarting..."
        logMsg ""

        #send emails out
        echo $PAGEMESSAGE | mail -s $PAGESUBJECT $EMAILLIST
fi
```

To test this, I deliberately killed the PID of my process I want monitored, so this cronjob would have to restart it, I also wanted to test the email capability.  The script restarts my process exactly like I want it, and I get the email.

However the email says in the message body: "MyServer: process not found in 
`the entire listing of ps -ef`.  Attempting to Restart... Please check log file in /tmp".  Also, the addresses that the email was sent to, are lines from `ps -ef` as well. As in my email had 2000 recipients.  Sample addresses: `grep@myServer.mydomain.com`, `process@myServer.mydomain.com`

Does anyone know whats going on?  Why is `mail` executing a command that is in a string?  Since finding this out, I have changed the string to remove any possibility of a unix command.

Comment: Quote your variables. Always. Just do it. Also look into `pgrep` instead of parsing `ps`. That all said I don't see how this could have the `ps -ef` output in the email. Also you should probably look into actual service supervisor tools. Many of them exist and are pretty good.

Comment: Without seeing the actual script, it's going to be hard to determine if there's a problem with it. Also, would this be more efficient? `if ! pgrep process; then...`

Comment: Honestly guys, this script is political.  Its to show a client that their process wont die on our servers, even though when it died, it wasn't our fault.  I am fully aware that there are better tools.  However, I wanted the lightest touch possible.